How to define the depth of recursive type in JSONSchema
I would like to ask if it is possible to restrict the depth of recursive type in JSON schema?
For example if I try to define a nested folder structure with maximum depth of 4.
Example:
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/FolderSchema",
  "definitions": {
    "FolderSchema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "folders": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "minLength": 0,
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Folder"
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "Folder": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "nested_folders" : {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "minLength": 0,
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Folder"
          }
        }
      },
      "title": " Folder"
    }

  }
}


You must define four levels explicitly. There is no keyword defined to constrain recursive depth
